# How to link DataSet to .aspx page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, xsd

I created a DataSet named CardInfo.xsd in Visual Studio 2015 that works perfectly

When I try to show data from it using a TableAdapter (which also works fine and displays the specific query I set up), I get an error in the code behind file.
It says `CardInfo is not defined` and also that the `TableAdapter (CardInfoTableAdapters.TableTableAdapter)` is not defined.

However it lets me select any other `.xsd` or `.mdf` files in the project, so I feel like the `DataSet` is not broadcasting itself to the rest of the project.

In the end it is supposed to get the value from the text box and show the row whose primary id matches the inputted number.
Here is the code to create the DataSet on the page:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Page.IsPostBack Then
        GetCardInfo(cardentry.Text)
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub GetCardInfo(ByVal Entry As String)
    Dim myDataSet As New CardInfo
    Dim cardDA As New CardInfoTableAdapters.TableTableAdapter

    cardDA.Fill(myDataSet.Entry, Entry)

    GridViewRetrieval.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables("Table")
    GridViewRetrieval.DataBind()
End Sub
```